# Add new points into a contour plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot some extra points onto an existing contour plot with ggplot2:

```
require(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) # for melt
volcano3d <- melt(volcano)
names(volcano3d) <- c("x", "y", "z")
v <- ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y, z = z))
v <- v + stat_contour()
print(v)
newdata <- data.frame(x = runif(7)*60, y = runif(7)*60)
v <- v + geom_point(data=newdata, aes(x, y))
print(v)
```

The first print is ok, but the second is just blank. Why?

Comment: Add `z=0` in the `aes()` of the last assignment. The plot expects 3 coordinates so it cannot place the points.

Comment: `ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y)) + stat_contour(aes(z = z)) + geom_point(data = newdata)`. You should also add the error message to your question.